# Assigning forEach to every image through 'img'

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, foreach

I am trying to use `forEach` in JS under the `img` tag on HTML

Here is the variable `bobbingPhotos`:

```
bobbingPhotos.forEach(function(photo) {
  var randomDelay = Math.random() * 2; // Random delay between 0 and 2 seconds
  photo.style.animationDelay = randomDelay + 's';
});
```

This can be solved through giving each and every image a hard coded `class="bobbing-photo"` but I cannot do that as my images are being generated through text inputs

```
function generateImages() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  var imageOutput = document.getElementById('imageOutput');
  imageOutput.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
    var character = userInput[i].toUpperCase();
    var element;

    if (character === "\n") {
  element = document.createElement('br');
}
else if (character === ' ') {
  element = document.createElement('img');
  element.src = 'FONT/SPACE.png';
}
else {
  var image = document.createElement('img');
  image.src = 'FONT/' + character + '.png';
  element = image;
  image.classList.add("bobbing-photo");
}
```

Even doing `image.classList.add("bobbing-photo")` does not make each and every image bob at a different time.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox so we can test your code ?

Comment: How does one provide a sandbox? @FlorentM.

Comment: There are a websites like playcode.io or codesandbox.io that allow you to use online IDEs. You can check https://playcode.io/javascript

Comment: @FlorentM. [link](https://1536391.playcode.io)

Comment: Your link doesn't works :/

Comment: @FlorentM. "Couldn't find entry file.
Tell PlayCode which file to run by adding one of this files: index.html, index.pug, script.js or main.js." - I apologise, but please may you find ways to create a sandbox. I cannot .

Answer (score 0):

Because you added the image tag dynamically, the animation function should be called again after add image tags.

```
function generateImages() {
  var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
  var imageOutput = document.getElementById('imageOutput');
  imageOutput.innerHTML = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
    var character = userInput[i].toUpperCase();
    var element;

    if (character === "\n") {
      element = document.createElement('br');
    }
    else if (character === ' ') {
      element = document.createElement('img');
      element.src = 'FONT/SPACE.png';
    }
    else {
      var image = document.createElement('img');
      image.src = 'FONT/' + character + '.png';
      element = image;
      image.classList.add("bobbing-photo");
    }
    imageOutput.appendChild(image);
  }
}
```

```
    generateImages();
    // todo here get elements by classname
    var bobbingPhotos = document.getElementsByClassName("bobbing-photo");
    // call animation function again
    bobbingPhotos.forEach(function(photo) {
      var randomDelay = Math.random() * 2; // Random delay between 0 and 2 seconds
      photo.style.animationDelay = randomDelay + 's';
    });
```

Comment: This is not working :(

Comment: Did you append image tags in document on generateImages function? It should be appended in document.

Comment: so define var bobbing photos right after  function generateImages()?

Comment: Please add following code in generateImages 
function.          imageOutput.appendChild(element);

Comment: It does not worok still?

Comment: please check again my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254554/discussion-between-nazar-zaplatinskiy-and-emmy).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified working example. If this works for you, maybe you can re-examine your own code and fix the issue?

EDIT: I think I understood your problem, you're probably not adding the delay AFTER the generation. See my updated example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <style>
    @keyframes bob-anim {
      from {top: 0px;}
      to {top: 20px;}
    }

    .bobbing-photo {
      position: relative;
      animation: bob-anim 0.2s infinite linear alternate;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="text" id="userInput" /> Press enter to submit.
  <div id="imageOutput" />
  <script>
    var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput');
    var imageOutput = document.getElementById('imageOutput');

    function generateImages() {
      var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;

      for (var i = 0, len = userInput.length; i < len; ++i) {
        // NOTE: I don't have the fonts as images, so will use the letters themselves.
        // var image = document.createElement('img');
        // image.src = 'FONTS/MY_LETTER.png'; <-- replace with your own logic
        // image.classList.add("bobbing-photo");
        // imageOutput.appendChild(image);

        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.textContent = userInput[i];
        span.classList.add("bobbing-photo");
        imageOutput.appendChild(span);
      }
    }

    userInput.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
      if (event.key === 'Enter') {
        while (imageOutput.hasChildNodes()) {
          imageOutput.removeChild(imageOutput.lastChild);
        }

        generateImages();

        var bobbingPhotos = document.querySelectorAll('.bobbing-photo');
        bobbingPhotos.forEach(function(photo) {
          var randomDelay = Math.random() * 2; // Random delay between 0 and 2 seconds
          photo.style.animationDelay = randomDelay + 's';
        });
      }
    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I cannot define the image as the images depend on the text input as provided in my quesiton

Comment: @emmy I understand, but it should be no different with having your sources as images of text characters or predefined image sources, so there's probably some other logical error somewhere.

Comment: So in theory, i would have to define and give bopping somewhere somehow to A-Z manually?

Comment: @emmy What i mean is that `image.src = 'https://picsum.photos/200/300';` and `image.src = 'FONT/' + character + '.png';` are equivalent. It might be that I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve. I assumed you were trying to make each separate image character bob. Also a bit confusing in your code is what is the difference between the variables `image` and `element`, why do you need both?

Comment: @emmy see my edit, I think I understood your problem, and you can try running the code snippet provided.

Comment: hi @b00t what must i remove in order to acheive image generation?

Comment: hi b00t, I have tried to replcae it but it is not coming out, also must it not be textarea?

Comment: @emmy What do you mean exactly by image generation? Because in your original example, you're just adding image files (for each letter) from your local device/ server. Or let me ask an other question. Could you explain without any code, as simply as possible, what exactly you're trying to achieve? Because I think the issue is, that we're not understanding what you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You could **apply the random delay immediately after creating** the image element like so:

```
function generateImages(text) {
  // reset
  imageOutput.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var character = text[i].toUpperCase();
    // default: create img
    var element = document.createElement("img");

    if (character === "\n") {
      // add line break
      element = document.createElement("br");
    } else if (character === " ") {
      element.src = "FONT/SPACE.png";
    } else {
      element.src = "FONT/" + character + ".png";
      element.classList.add("bobbing-photo");

      // Random delay between 0 and 2 seconds
      var randomDelay = Math.random() * 2; 
      element.style.animationDelay = -randomDelay + "s";
    }
    // append
    imageOutput.append(element);
  }
}
```

There is no need to run a separate loop.

```js
var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput");
var imageOutput = document.getElementById("imageOutput");

userInput.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
  let text = e.currentTarget.value;
  generateImages(text);
});


function generateImages(text) {
  // reset
  imageOutput.innerHTML = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    var character = text[i].toUpperCase();
    // default: create img
    var element = document.createElement("img");

    if (character === "\n") {
      // add line break
      element = document.createElement("br");
    } else if (character === " ") {
      //element.src = "FONT/SPACE.png";
      element.src = generateTextSvg(character);
    } else {
      //element.src = "FONT/" + character + ".png";
      element.src = generateTextSvg(character);
      element.classList.add("bobbing-photo");
      var randomDelay = Math.random() * 2; // Random delay between 0 and 2 seconds
      element.style.animationDelay = -randomDelay + "s";
      // optional: random bobbing amplitude
      element.style.top = randomDelay + "em";
    }
    // append
    imageOutput.append(element);
  }
}

/**
* just for demonstration
*/

function generateTextSvg(text) {
  let svg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <text x="50%" y="50%" dy="10%" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" font-size="100">${text}</text>
</svg>`;
  let dataUrl = `data:image/svg+xml,` + encodeURIComponent(svg);
  return dataUrl;
}
```

```css
.bobbing-photo {
  position: relative;
  animation: bobbing 0.3s infinite forwards alternate ease-in-out;
}



@keyframes bobbing {
  to {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="userInput" placeholder="enter text">
<div id="imageOutput" />
```

In the example above I'm using a dynamically generated svg converted to a data URL.